# Run a MySql function over results of join tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query where it returns results based on a user inputted categories and products. See below.

```
    SELECT * from locations_categories as lscs
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categories.code IN (?)) as cat
    ON lscs.category_id = cat.id
    LEFT JOIN locations as loc 
    ON loc.id = lscs.location_id
    LEFT JOIN product_locations as prodloc
    ON prodloc.location_id = loc.id
    INNER JOIN products as prod 
    on prod.id = prodloc.product_id
    AND prod.id IN (?)
```

So for example if I was to put in category 1 with product 40 it would return all locations that were in category one and also had product 40.

The issue i'm having now is I have a `Haversine(initialLat,InitialLong,FinalLat,finalLong`) function. But I have no idea how to only run haversine on the results of the above query.

The initialLat and initialLong are user provided via postman and the finalLat and finalLong come from the results of the above joins.

How could I iterate through the results of the above joins and run them through the haversine function to determine how far the locations are from the user provided location?

EDIT:::

The top two numbers are the user inputted long and lat. The array is the results of the above query. The variables used for the long and lat of the user inputted data is $request->lon and $request->lat, these are what is provided in the haversine functions first two parameters, the second two parameters need to come from each of the two results of the array.

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to have some sample data.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I will edit the question right now

Comment: @user3783243 you helped lead me to the solution, if you post as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The haversine formula should be put into the list of fields you want to select. Mysql will then run the equation and return the distance for you. For example:

```
SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM
```

will give the distance between the passed lat/lng and the locations in the DB.

The google store locator tutorial has good examples of this, https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator#finding-locations-with-mysql. (Note it is out of date, `mysql_` should no longer be used)